# How to rotate image to its default orientation selected from gallery in Android?

Tags: android, orientation, android-gallery

When ever I select image from gallery and set it in image view. It becomes rotated. I want it in its default orientation.

Comment: Explain in detail. What have you done so far!!

Comment: Add your code here that shows how you write the code!!

Comment: I searched a solution for it and i wan to share it with others ... as answer to my question

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me properly (this code is combination from two different sources) to solve image rotation when selected from gallery.

```
   @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        Uri uri = data.getData();

        try {
                //..First convert the Image to the allowable size so app do not throw Memory_Out_Bound Exception
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri), null, options);
                int resolution = 500;
                    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, resolution  , resolution);
                    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri), null, options);

                //...Now You have the 'bitmap' to rotate....
                //...Rotate the bitmap to its original Orientation...
                Bitmap bitmapNew = ImageOrientation.modifyOrientation(getApplicationContext(),bitmap,uri);

                //...After Rotation set the image to Image View...
                    imageViewProfile.setImageBitmap(bitmapNew);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Image_exception",e.toString());
        }
    }

}
public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

The Source code of ImageOrientation class is..You have to call only modifyOrientation() method from Activity or where ever you need.

```
   public class ImageOrientation {


    public static Bitmap modifyOrientation(Context context,Bitmap bitmap,Uri uri ) throws IOException {
        ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(getPath(context,uri));
        int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                return rotate(bitmap, 90);

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                return rotate(bitmap, 180);

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                return rotate(bitmap, 270);

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
                return flip(bitmap, true, false);

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL:
                return flip(bitmap, false, true);

            default:
                return bitmap;
        }
    }

    private static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }

                // TODO handle non-primary volumes
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
     * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
     *
     * @param context The context.
     * @param uri The Uri to query.
     * @param selection (Optional) Filter used in the query.
     * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
     * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
     */
    private static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                       String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {
                column
        };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     */
    private static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     */
    private static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     */
    private static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }



    private static Bitmap rotate(Bitmap bitmap, float degrees) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(degrees);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }

    private static Bitmap flip(Bitmap bitmap, boolean horizontal, boolean vertical) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.preScale(horizontal ? -1 : 1, vertical ? -1 : 1);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }


}
```

Comment: You did find solution!! Great!

Comment: Try this solution and mark as help full so others could be able to get it

Answer (score 2):

for getting correct orientaion after selecting from gallery/Camera:

```
ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(photoPath);
int orientation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

switch(orientation) {
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
        rotateImage(bitmap, 90);
        break;
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
        rotateImage(bitmap, 180);
        break;
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
        rotateImage(bitmap, 270);
        break;
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
    default:
        break;
}


public Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap source, float angle) {
    Matrix mat = new Matrix();
    mat.postRotate(angle);

    Bitmap bitmap= Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), mat,

    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: this requires angle... 
But the solution I answered is make the picture to default and it is full code from choosing to setting in image view

Comment: nightcoder, he just needs to get the image in the correct orientation, that I answered. I don't know why are you putting whole onActivityResult method here.Also, It does not require angle manually the code will detect automatically, what do you want to tell me by your comment ?

Comment: Arun Kumar, don't get exhaustive. I did't said your answer is incorrect !

Comment: I put all code because, any other person just need to copy and paste the code for the beginners too.
So there would be no ambiguity that where to put that   ExifInterface code.

Comment: Just tell me one thing ...  here ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(photoPath);
where to find that photoPath ? if you are selecting image from gallery. It gives you image rather then photoPath.

Comment: Writing in two comments Even if you are selecting image from gallery you can get the path of image

in your onActivityResult in the case of gallery : 

onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
        filePathColumn, null, null, null);

Comment: cursor.moveToFirst();int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();File imageFile = getImageFile(imgDecodableString);}

Answer (score 0):

To solve image rotation when selected from gallery, I have used this and It works for me.

```
SaveCompressImage mSaveCompressImage = new SaveCompressImage(getApplicationContext());
            String path = mSaveCompressImage.compressImage(imageFilePath);
```

SaveCompressImage.java

```
public class SaveCompressImage {
    Context context;
    public SaveCompressImage(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }

    public String compressImage(String imageUri) {
        String filename=null ;
        try {
            String filePath = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri) ;
            Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            // by setting this field as true, the actual bitmap pixels are not
            // loaded in the memory. Just the bounds are loaded. If
            // you try the use the bitmap here, you will get null.
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);


            int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
            int actualWidth = options.outWidth;

            // max Height and width values of the compressed image is taken as
            // 816x612

            float maxHeight = 816.0f;
            float maxWidth = 612.0f;
            float imgRatio = (float)actualWidth / actualHeight;
            float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;

            // width and height values are set maintaining the aspect ratio of the
            // image

            if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
                if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {
                    imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
                    actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);
                    actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
                } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
                    imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
                    actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
                    actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
                } else {
                    actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
                    actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;

                }
            }

            // setting inSampleSize value allows to load a scaled down version of
            // the original image

            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth,
                    actualHeight);

            // inJustDecodeBounds set to false to load the actual bitmap
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

            // this options allow android to claim the bitmap memory if it runs low
            // on memory
            options.inPurgeable = true;
            options.inInputShareable = true;
            options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

            try {
                // load the bitmap from its path
                bmp =BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {

            }
            try {
                scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight,
                        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            }
            if(scaledBitmap!=null){
                float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
                float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
                float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
                float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;

                Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
                scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
                canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
                canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2,
                        middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(
                                Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

                // check the rotation of the image and display it properly
                ExifInterface exif;
                try {
                    exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);

                    int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                            ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
                    Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    if (orientation == 6) {
                        matrix.postRotate(90);
                        Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
                    } else if (orientation == 3) {
                        matrix.postRotate(180);
                        Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
                    } else if (orientation == 8) {
                        matrix.postRotate(270);
                        Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
                    }
                    scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,
                            scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix,
                            true);
                } catch (IOException ioExceptione) {

                }
                FileOutputStream out = null;
                filename = getFilename();
                try {
                    out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
                    // write the compressed bitmap at the destination specified by
                    // filename.
                    scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {

        }
        return filename;
    }

    public String getFilename() {
        File file = new File(Constants.IMAGE_STORE_FOLDER);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        String uriSting = (Constants.IMAGE_STORE_FOLDER
                + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
        return uriSting;
    }

    public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height
                    / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }
        final float totalPixels = (float)width * height;
        final float totalReqPixelsCap = (float)reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;
        while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
            inSampleSize++;
        }
        return inSampleSize;
    }

    /**
     * Get a file path from a Uri. This will get the the path for Storage Access
     * Framework Documents, as well as the _data field for the MediaStore and
     * other file-based ContentProviders.
     *
     * @param context The context.
     * @param uri The Uri to query.
     * @author paulburke
     */

    public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;
        boolean a=DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri);
        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat ) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }
                // handle non-primary volumes
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();

            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
     * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
     *
     * @param context The context.
     * @param uri The Uri to query.
     * @param selection (Optional) Filter used in the query.
     * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
     * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
     */
    public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {
                column
        };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
     */
    public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    public String getRealPathFromURI(String contentURI) {
        Uri contentUri = Uri.parse(contentURI);
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,
                null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            return contentUri.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int index = cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            String pathh=cursor.getString(index);
            return pathh;
        }
    }
}
```